# How to store 32 bit integer variable in pure C on 8051 uC

Tags: c, integer, bit, 8051

I am trying to write some soft on 8051 uC in C. Problem is that the longest integer is equal 16 bits. Is it possible to create my own 32 bit unsigned integer variable? Of course it should support all operations like +, -, << etc.

If it is not possible what is alternative? For me the only way which comes to my mind is to have two 16 bit integers. But in that solution I think I can't use standard operators. During all operations I would have to remember modifing two integers.

Is there any better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's some [info on `stdint.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/stdint.h.html), introduced as part of the C99 standard, which should be available on most modern C compilers.  As @H2CO3 mentions, it provides the `uint32_t` type which is guaranteed to be an unsigned 32bit integer.

Comment: I am using C51 COMPILER V8.05a. It is for 8051 uC. Using unsigned long solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your compiler/libc implementation conforms to C99, you can use the

```
uint32_t
```

type to represent 32-bit unsigned integers. If it doesn't, you can still give

```
unsigned long
```

a try (print its sizeof to see how big it is).

Comment: uint32_t is optional in C 1999.

Comment: You can also try long long. if all else fails, you can always write a light bignum set of functions.

Comment: @Aslai `long long` is also C99-dependent.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My compiler doesn't support uin32_t, but unsigned long works fine. It has 4 bytes.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation".